# Flycheck-Haskell - "Opening Directory" "Not a directory"

Tags: flycheck, haskell-mode

I'm trying to get flycheck working in Haskell, however, when I try to do anything to do with flycheck, even running stuff like `flycheck-verify-setup`, I get an error "Not a directory".

Does anyone have any idea why this might be happening? Flycheck works in every other language, it's just Haskell.

Comment: Updating packages fixed this for me today.

Answer (score 1):

This was frustrating me too :| It's got to do with how Flycheck searches for the `stack.yaml` file. It's being fixed on Flycheck:

https://github.com/flycheck/flycheck/issues/1291

https://github.com/flycheck/flycheck/pull/1292